# Extended display resolution stuck at 800x600 when using an USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, extended-desktop

I have a Dell laptop that has USB 2.0 port and I have a monitor that supports HDMI/VGA/display ports full HD.

I used a USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter ([Nextech NA34](https://nextechbyamson.com/product/usb-3-0-to-hdmi-adapter/)) and it's working.

But extended monitor resolution is stuck at 800×600.

Is there any option that can be used to display higher resolution?

Comment: The adpater is designed to work with USB3.0 and a fairly recent computer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a solution to my problem. I think USB 2.0 supports maximum 800 resolution and my laptop has micro HDMI port while monitor has normal HDMI port. So, I purchased a micro HDMI to HDMI cable and now its supporting maximum resolution available in laptop.